# PostGIS : Find direction between custom GPS tracks (linestrings) intersected with pgr_dijkstra route

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I have many custom GPS tracks(linestrings) and a route generated by pgr_dijkstra by giving source & destination as input. Using ST_Intersects, I able to filter required GPS tracks belongs to the route generated by pgr_dijkstra. Now I wanted to classify intersected GPS tracks direction like how many GPS tracks are from source to destination and how many belongs from destination to source. What are some possible methods to find direction (A->B / B->A) between 2 linestrings?

[image]

Comment: look at the start and end points and count how many are A and how many are B?

Comment: Ian, thanks for your help. have added a picture to illustrate. Green Line (A->B / B->A) is the route generated by pgr_dijkstra. GPS tracks (1,2 & 3) are the linestrings intersecting over the green line. I know the start & end point of GPS tracks. now need to classify like,, track 1 & 2 passed from A->B & track 3 passed from B->A. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have got desired result by calculating separately Azimuth between A->B and gps tracks(1,2,3). wrote python snippet to classify direction and validated the logic by visualizing in kml.

Comment: Please share your code so that others can profit.